# node-webkit Helper memory management

Tags: node.js, memory, chromium, node-webkit

I am coding a lightweight single page app `node-webkit` app. Recently I've been doing some memory profiling in order to detect memory leaks and keep the app usable even on older systems.
I found out that my code itself is pretty memory efficient, but the `node-webkit Helper` process which runs it keeps eating more and more ram as time goes by.
To provide a simple "restart" function I simply reload the page; I thought this would also clear most of the objects in memory, but I found out that node-webkit Helper's memory usage actually increases by almost 10 MB at each reload!
In [this issue thread](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/149) on node-webkit's issues page I found out this magical line of code

```
require('nw-gui').Window.get().reload(3)
```

which seems to reload the page while cleaning up some memory (I usually end up around 50 MB for node-webkit plus the ~15 MB required by my app), but it is kinda hacky (also, it can be executed only once on the same page apparently, so I have to chain it with `location.reload()` to implement the "clear everything and restart" functionality).
Does anyone have any clue about how to keep node-webkit's Helper memory usage at bay and/or provide some kind of "restart" function in a less hacky way? Explanations of how memory management works in node-webkit's context are appreciated, as this topics seems quite complex and there aren't many easily understandable sources on it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Pretty interested in that too

Comment: Any news on this? Have you solved?